# Is it neccesary to use copy inside classes to avoid overwriting previous variables?

Tags: arrays, class, numpy, python-3.5

I write a simple class which has an initialization phase depending on some variable, it overwrites the previous variable.

Is it strictly necessary to make a copy when giving inputs in order to not overwrite the variable?

To exemplify:

```
import numpy as np
Input = np.array([ [0,1], [1,1] ])
class A:
    def __init__(self, I):
        self.B = I
```

When I write:

```
Trial = A(Input)
Trial.B
```

It gives correctly:

```
array[[0,1]
      [1,1]]
```

If I want to make a complete change, such as:

```
Trial.B = 'Hello'
```

It **does not change the Input**. However, if I repeat all this until this point, and now we write instead of this change another one like:

```
Trial.B[0] = 2
```

Now if I ask for Input, it gives:

```
np.array([[2,2]
          [1,1]])
```

Now it has changed the variable Input!

Why is this happening? Do I have to always write:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, I):
        self.B = I.copy()
```

In order to not mess the variable? Why does it only mess it when the type of data changed is the same as in the variable?

Thanks.

Comment: The fact that `self.B` is an attribute of a class object doesn't change things.  `B = A` just shares a pointer to a common object.  `B[0] = ...` modifies that shared object (provided it is a `mutable` object like list, dictionary or numpy array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Trial.B` had a pointer to `Input` and you changed the pointer to `'Hello'`.

In second example you accessed data that `Trial.B` points to and altered it.

If you were to test `Input` and `Trial.B` using:

```
Trial.B is Input
#True
```

You'd get this results which indicates that both point to same object.